# Big O for the following Python function example

Tags: python, for-loop, big-o

What would be the Big-O for the following function?

```
for a in range(n):
        for b in range(n - a):
            for c in range(n - b):
                if a + b + c == 0:
                    break
            if a + b == 0:
                break
        if a == 0:
            break
    return n + 1
```

I was thinking that it would be O(N^3) since there is a triple nested for loop and each of the components of the for loop would have a Big O of O(N). Is my thinking correct or is there possibly a different Big-O for this function?

Comment: Every loop breaks in the first iteration, so O(1)

Comment: actually the innermost loop breaks first, so yes, O(1). But the indentation needs to be fixed

Comment: This function is quite useless. Are you sure this is actually the code you meant to ask about?

Comment: Very simply, you trace through the code to see how it works; pay special attention to how many times each statement will execute, expressed as a function of `n`.  "Big O" is (basically) the limit of that function as `n` approaches infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is O(1).  It's not because of the loops, it's because of the logic.  Look closely at the range values.  The Range function, when used with a single parameter, gives you a range object which functions somewhat like a list [0, ..., n].  For each loop there, the first value that each a, b, and c have will always be 0.  So you'll always hit that a+b+c==0 break.

I'm guessing this is for a homework assignment?  You can always try running it yourself a few times, just to see what the output looks like.  Modifying the code to do something like the below might give you a decent idea of what's going on inside the function.

```
def sample_func(n):
    total = 0
    for a in range(n):
        for b in range(n - a):
            for c in range(n - b):
                total += 1
                if a + b + c == 0:
                    break
            if a + b == 0:
                break
        if a == 0:
            break
    print( total)
    return n + 1

for i in range(20):
    sample_func(i)
```

Comment: Nice first answer, but if I may nitpick, `range` does not return a list, it returns a `range` object. In some contexts that is an important difference.

Comment: In Python 3 that is. `range` did return a list in Python 2.

Comment: Good to know, thank you.  Edited.